# Firebase is working fine on Unity3D Editor but have some dependencies issues on actuall Android devices

Tags: android, database, firebase, authentication, unity-game-engine

I am new to firebase. I tried to integrate firebase SDK 5.0.0 and firebase SDK 4.5.0 with Unity 2017.4.0f1 and Unity 5.5.3p4 it shows some error "Gradle failed to fetch dependencies". It is working fine on Unity Editor. I tried the quick samples and it successfully added data to database and auth is working fine on Unity editor but when I build an apk and run on actuall android device it doesn't work. It shows that "one or more firebase dependencies are not present". It have spent a lot of time googling the issue but haven't find any useful solution.[image: Error on device]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. In case if someone having this problem.
Please do the following:
1- Update Play service resolver
2- Delete the file located on "C:\Users{username}.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.2.1-bin\dajvke9o8kmaxbu0kc5gcgeju\gradle-4.2.1-bin.zip 
3- Asset->Play Service Resolver->Android -> Force resolve

this will resolve the issue hopefully. worked for me.